# how to use for each with nested array

Tags: javascript

I want to log each occurrence of the letter an in this array, the expected output should be 3 a's, but there are none because it does dot read nested arrays does anyone know a solution.

```
let items = [["a","b"],["c","a"],["b","a"]];
items.forEach((v) => (v === "a" && console.log(v)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the array before looping, which will work for any level of nesting.

```js
let items = [["a","b"],["c","a"],["b","a"]];
items.flat(Infinity).forEach((v) => (v === "a" && console.log(v)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Flat array > Filter array > Foreach on filtered array

```js
    let items = [["a","b"],["c","a"],["b","a"]];
    items.flat(Infinity)
         .filter((v) => (v === "a"))
         .forEach((v) => (console.log(v)));
```